# Regex substring matching on capture group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have an advanced regex question (unless I am overthinking this).

With my basic knowledge of Regex, it is trivial to match static capture group further down in the string.

```
P(.): D:\1
```

Correctly matches

```
Pb: Db
Pa: Da
```

and (correctly) does not match

```
Pa: D:b
```

So far so good. However, what I need to capture is a set of [a-z]+ after the P and match the one character. So that these should also match:

```
Pabc: D:c
Pabc: D:a
Pba: D:b
Pba: D:a
```

but not

```
Pabc: D:x
Pba: D:g
```

I started going down the path of writing separate patterns like so (spaces added around the alternation for clarity):

```
P(.): D:\1 | P(.)(.): D:(\1|\2) | P(.)(.)(.): D:(\1|\2|\3)
```

But I cannot make even this clumsy solution work in Javascript Regex.

Is there an elegant, correct way to do this? Can it be done with Javascript's limited engine?

Comment: The two patterns you posted have multiple trailing spaces, whereas the text you're trying to match doesn't - might consider fixing that

Comment: (spaces added around the alternation for clarity)  see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex will do it:

```
P.*(.).*: D:\1
```

`.*(.).*` will match one or more characters, capturing one of them.

If the captured character matches the character after `D:`, then the regex matches.

If the captured character doesn't match, backtracking will ensure that it tries again with a different captured character, until all combinations have been tried.

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/7IV1v4/2) for running example.

Comment: Danke schoen, Andreas. Great answer!